# Power BI Report Server Dec 2023

Tags: server, powerbi, report

I have just loaded the Power BI Desktop December 2023 version. But I cannot publish to my on-prem Report Server because it is the September 2023 version. When will the Report Server be upgraded to the match the Dec 2023 desktop version?

I have tried publishing to my current Report Server and I get a message saying my rpeort is corrupted. My research into this seems to says that the Report Server version must match the Desktop version. (understandble) But I cannot find any updates to Report Server.